# Angular 5 - Issue editing array with function

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having some trouble with a function call. First of all here is the data:

```
this.widgets = [
{ id: 1, title: 'widget', config: { sizex: 1 } }
]
```

And here is the function:

```
editIT(id, prop, value) {
  var elem = this.widgets.find(elem => elem.id === id);
  if (elem !== null) {
    elem[prop] = value;
  }
}
```

My problem is that I can edit the title, like this:

```
<button (click)="editIT(1, 'title', 'some other title')">Edit Title</button>
```

The above works but I now want to edit the sizex property, like this:

```
<button (click)="editIT(1, 'config.sizex', 2)">Edit Sizex</button>
```

And the sizex is not being edited.

What I'm i doing wrong?

Comment: Square bracket syntax will not work for nested values, it treats the `.` as part of the key, so it's actually looking for a a key 'config.sizex' in your widget object

Comment: So what do I use?

Comment: You should check if the string has dots in it, and then use it like [prop][subprop] where prop is the string before the dot subprop is the string after the dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that iterates the nested keys for you and updated the value:

```
editIT(id, prop, value) {
  var elem = this.widgets.find(elem => elem.id === id);
  if (elem !== null) {
    updateValue(prop, elem, value);
  }
}

function updateValue(key, obj, value) {
    let keys = key.split(".");
    let finalKey = keys.pop();
    let finalObj = keys.reduce((res, key) => res[key], obj);
    finalObj[finalKey] = value;
}
```